# Data loss during Serial.Write method

Tags: c#, c, winforms, serial-port

Now I would like to use WinForms to develop a GUI to control a embedded board.

Between WinForm and the embedded board, serial communication is utilized.

Currently, result of reading data is well.

However, writing data with `Serial.Write` method did not perform well.
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.8

Some characters were not received by the board. 
the result is show in the following:

[image: Reading Result]

```cs
     private void ButtonSendCommand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          byte[] txdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TXTBoxCommand.Text);
          OBCSerialPort.Write(txdata, 0, txdata.Length);
          OBCSerialPort.Write(Environment.NewLine);
     }
```

in my embedded board, I use `scanf` to get command and decode them

```c
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", cStr);
```

And decode function:

```c
void decode_context(char *str)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;  
    uint8_t argc = 0; //number of argument
    char *p = strtok(str, " ");
    char *cBuf[MAX_INPUT_LEN];
    command_t* pCase = 0;
    struct cmd_context ctx;

    // Split input string with space 
    while (p != NULL){
        cBuf[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        argc++;
    }

    if(argc < Max_ARGC){

        // Duplicate arg & argc to command context
        memcpy(ctx.arg, cBuf, sizeof(cBuf[0])*argc);
        memcpy(&ctx.argc, &argc, sizeof(uint8_t));

        // Linear serach for key of instruction
        for(pCase = command
         ; pCase != command + sizeof(command) / sizeof(command[0])
         ; pCase++)
        {
            if(0 == strcmp(pCase->name, ctx.arg[0])) {
               (*pCase->handler)(&ctx);
                break;
            }

            if(pCase == command-1 + sizeof(command)/sizeof(command[0]))
                printf("\n\r\t  Not defined command:'%s' Please refer instruction set!\n", ctx.arg[0]);      
        }

    }
    else
        printf("\n\r\t Error: too many arguments ! \n\r");

}
```

P.S.Before the development of this GUI, I have used `Tera Term` to communicate with the board and both reading and writing performed well.
Configuration is :

- Receiving:    CR, encoding with UTF8
- Transmitting: LF, encoding with UTF8

Does anyone figure out why it happened just like that?

- **Update**

I have solved this issue after I modified writing process:

```cs
  int index = 0;
  byte[] txdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TXTBoxCommand.Text);
                while (index < txdata.Length)
                {
                    OBCSerialPort.Write(txdata, index, 1);
                    index++;
                    if (index == txdata.Length)
                        OBCSerialPort.Write("\n");
                }
```

It seems that for my embedded board using `OBCSerialPort.Write` to transmit multiple bytes will cause data loss.

However, it does not make sense...

Comment: C# is not C, they are different languages

Comment: Two things: Are you sure that the data you send contains a trailing white-space? And will the data you read fit into the buffer you have, *including* the ending null-terminator?

Comment: Also, `pCase == command-1 + sizeof(command)/sizeof(command[0])` seems wrong to me. First of all, is `command` an actual array and not a pointer? Secondly, I would really put the check for missing command *after* the loop (in which case it would be `pCase == command + sizeof(command) / sizeof(command[0])`).

Comment: scanf is unix/linux which only uses a return '\r' while windows '\n' sends both a return and linefeed.  So the extra line is due to the '\n'.  Use '\r' instead.

Comment: command is a struct that I have defined myself.

Comment: @jdweng do you mean using `OBCSerialPort.Write('\r")` instead? But the argument used scanf means I have to send a newline character to stop transmission .

Comment: A '\n' in linux is one character while '\n'  in c# is two characters.

Comment: I can hardly see the C# in this question. Maybe there is a problem with using such low level stuff in a language with such amazing high level support for streams and arrays etc.

Comment: @jdweng I have tried what you said. However, the situation is still same..

Comment: I have solved this issue. However, I still don't get it..